# initial-scale=1.0 not working for iphone on specific server

Tags: iphone, html, meta-tags

I'm working on a small project for myself. It's a small webapp. I wanted to make it responsive for iPhone by just using some css media queries.
That's all working fine but I'm confused about one issue. The initial-scale=1.0 meta tag isn't working on my production server. It works perfectly fine on my development server and it's also working on another production server that I had available.
It also occurs on multiple phones.

I can't really understand why a meta tag should fail on a specific server. As far as I'm concerned these should have doing to do with the server the code is hosted on.

If you look at labs.wooltown.nl/split you'll see the problem. If you look at kuacha.net/split, you'll see how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume it's got something to do with having frames. I haven't tested/read about how scaling works in frames, but try adding the meta tag on the frameset page.

Comment: That is brilliant! That's exactly it. Will have to talk to the hosting provider about that frameset though because they include since multiple tld's need to point to this site. And unfortunately I can't control that frameset. Thanks!